# VBA script crashes every time

Tags: vba, excel

I am novice to Excel and from a bit of researching, found a code that generates value in a cell based on the value entered in another cell and vice-versa. The code is as below. But every time I make a small change on the worksheet, it just stops working and does not reset even after a shut down and reopen.

kindly help with suggestions. thanks!

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim EF As Range, t As Range, v As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    Set t = Target
    Set EF = Range("E:F")
    If Intersect(t, EF) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        r = t.Row
        v = t.Value
        If v = "" Then
            Range("E" & r & ":F" & r).Value = ""
        End If
        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            If Intersect(t, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
                t.Offset(0, 1).Value = v * 25.4
            Else
                t.Offset(0, -1).Value = v / 25.4
            End If
        End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Suggestion, put a breakpoint on the first line of your code, then modify a cell.  Step through your code with the debugger until you find your problem.  Probably due to recursive event triggering: there are techniqus to prevent this, e.g. : http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1210787

Answer (score 4):

Why does it not work?

You have `application.EnableEvents=False` in your code. When you make an error, and the Events are disabled, then they stay disabled. Try the following, to make your code working somehow.

Run this in a module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TurnMeOn()

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

To work further with your code, make sure that you are using good Error catchers, that reset the EnableEvents back, when they are present.

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        Dim EF          As Range
        Dim t           As Range
        Dim v           As Variant
        Dim r           As Long

       On Error GoTo Worksheet_Change_Error

        Set t = Target
        Set EF = Range("E:F")

        If Intersect(t, EF) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        r = t.Row
        v = t.Value
        Debug.Print Target.Address

        If v = "" Then
            Range("E" & r & ":F" & r).Value = ""
        End If

        If IsNumeric(v) Then
            If Intersect(t, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
                t.Offset(0, 1).Value = v * 25.4
            Else
                t.Offset(0, -1).Value = v / 25.4
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True

       On Error GoTo 0
       Exit Sub

Worksheet_Change_Error:

        Application.EnableEvents = True
        MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure Worksheet_Change of VBA Document Tabelle1"

    End Sub
```

A quick and dirty fix, to make the code working would be to change `Set t = Target` to             `Set t = Target(1,1)`. Thus, it would work always only with the first cell when multiple cells are pasted.

Answer (score 1):

How to restore the `Application.EnableEvents = True` is already given in @Vityata answer.

However, your code consists of so many unnecessary variables:

`t As Range` - equals `Target`

`v As Variant` - equals `Target.Value`

`r As Long` - equals `Target.Row`

You could just use the "Cleaner" version below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E:F")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False

        If Target.Value = "" Then
            Range("E" & Target.Row & ":F" & Target.Row).Value = ""
        End If
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            If Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = Target.Value * 25.4
            Else
                Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Target.Value / 25.4
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub
```